# PowerShell and JSON - how to check if JSON variable with multiple values contains value from variable which is a list

Tags: json, powershell

My JSON contains this part with multiple values in `EnvironmentIds` variable:

```
Name: Test
EnvironmentIds : {Environments-102, Environments-103}
```

If I would have simple variable `$ENV` with single value I would know how to check if that value exists in that list.

```
$ENVIRONMENT="Environments-103"

$json | ForEach-Object {
if ($_.EnvironmentIds -contains "$ENVIRONMENT") {
                              Write-Host($_.Name,$ENVIRONMENT)
                              }
```

But what should I do, if `$ENVIRONMENT` is not a single value but a list:

```
$ENVIRONMENT =  @ ("Environments-103", "Environments-104")
```

How to check if element from this list belongs - it is contained within the `EnvironmentIds` json list?
I want to print that specific value from the list which is contained in the JSON values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what should I do, if $ENVIRONMENT is not a single value but a list:

`Where-Object` would be a natural fit for this

```
$data = @{
    Name =  "Test"
    EnvironmentIds = "Environments-102", "Environments-103"
}

$ENVIRONMENT = "Environments-103", "Environments-104"

$matches = $ENVIRONMENT | Where-Object { $data.EnvironmentIds -eq $_ }

Write-Host $matches
```

Note that `-eq` works on arrays (`1,2,3,4,5 -eq 4` results in `4`). The above prints:

```
Environments-103
```

If there is more than one match, it will print more than one result.

Of course you can turn it around, same thing:

```
$matches = $data.EnvironmentIds | Where-Object { $ENVIRONMENT -eq $_ }
```

Comment: Hi Tomalak,
thanks for the assistance but you change my current object $._ on which I am iterating. I did not want that. As you see I am already printing the Name from my current object on which I am iterating with $._
Write-Host($_.Name...) - it is importnat for me to keep that current iteration. 
Iteration for the "ENVIRONEMENT" should be the second one, which is related to my current iteration , where in the same time I am extracting the name from current object.

Comment: @AndreyDonald `data.EnvironmentIds | Where-Object { $ENVIRONMENT -eq $_ } | ForEach-Object { ... }`